# Queryselector when Element is available

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

Is there any way I can make a function that finds the requested element using e.g. `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` when that requested element is available?

I'm playing around with the google maps api, and the map first loads after a few seconds. Meanwhile, I'm requesting an infowindow-element from the map, but the element is not available until the google map has fully loaded. Altough, queryselecting the requested element is performed before the map is fully loaded.

This puts me with an empty requested element.

How can I make a queryselector or if..else that returns the requested element when it is available? Is this possible?

Comment: Google has event handlers for this, hook into those

Comment: @adeneo Yes, but I'm using Vue.js, a javascript framework. With vue, i'm using a module that can't access the map event-handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a silly temporary solution with setInterval, like this:

```
     var timer = setInterval(function(){
            let background = document.querySelectorAll(".gm-style-iw");
            if (background.length > 0) {
                background.forEach(function(win) {
                    win.previousElementSibling.style.display = "none";
                });
                clearInterval(timer)
            }
        }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me for a react application.

```
let element= querySelector("#test")
if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
    // element.style
}
```